# Is ROS industrial supported on ABB's IRB 1520 or IRB 1600 robots?

Tags: ros, abb, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The website   http://wiki.ros.org/Robots   says that ROS is supported only on

ABB IRB 2400, IRB 5400, IRB 6640

We want to know what it would take to have ROS industrial support ABB IRB 1520 and  IRB 1600 robots.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200272/is-ros-industrial-supported-on-abb%27s-irb-1520-or-irb-1600-robots-?/) by [gayathrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/21265/gayathrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: driver should work, you need to create robot support (urdf + meshes) and MoveIt packages.

---

For robots to be included on the list you're linking, the following packages need to exist for a specific robot:

1. a 'description' package (or [robot support package](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/WorkingWithRosIndustrialRobotSupportPackages) as they are called in ROS-Industrial). This package contains the URDF, meshes and some launch files
2. MoveIt configuration package: this allows users to make use of MoveIt for motion control.
3. and most importantly: a driver package, which allows ROS-Industrial -- either using [industrial_robot_client](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_robot_client) nodes, or custom ones -- to connect to and command the appropriate industrial controller.

The [abb_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver) package is *manipulator agnostic*: it supports all robot models that an IRC5 controller supports. That means the driver should work with the IRB1520 and IRB1600.

What is currently not part of the standard distribution of ROS-Industrial packages are the models (urdf + meshes) and the MoveIt packages. Those you'll need to create for the models you mentioned.

If you'd like to contribute back, it would be preferable if you base your work on one of the existing support packages, such as the [abb_irb2400_support](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/tree/hydro-devel/abb_irb2400_support) package. You can just use the files and directory structure as a template.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3